# Drupal Taxonomy Block, Vocabulary Listing

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy

I looking for the best way to implement a block that lists all terms of a certain vocabulary. Each term should link to page that lists all nodes associated with that term. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here for a great tutorial to achieve exactly what you want

http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-add-block-menu-tags-or-other-taxonomy-terms-drupal-site

Comment: This is another solid option. In fact, I'd choose Taxonomy Menu over Views if you're displaying a hierarchical vocabulary, since it automatically handles parent/child term relationships. That's a bit more difficult to handle in Views. Also note though that you have less control over sorting (among other things) than you do with Views.

Comment: this does look promising, i'll give this a shot also.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to approach this would probably be to use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), and simply create a new view of the type "term". Here's a quick example which assumes that you have some basic familiarity with the Views UI:

1. Visit Views > Add (build/views/add), give your new view a name, and select **Term** from the "View type" radio buttons.
2. On the next page, start by adding a **Taxonomy: Vocabulary** filter and selecting your vocabulary in the filter settings.
3. Add a **Taxonomy: Term** field and enable the **Link this field to its taxonomy term page** option in the field settings. You might also want to remove the field's label, since this is just a simple listing.
4. You probably want your display to display *all* terms in your vocabulary, so change the "Items to display" **0 (unlimited)**. By default, new views only display 10 items at a time.
5. Check out the **Live preview** below to see if it's outputting what you need.
6. Add a new **Block** display using the dropdown on the left side of the Views UI.
7. Give your new block a name in the "Block settings" area. This is the description that will appear on Drupal's block admin page.
8. Save your view and visit admin/build/block to place and configure your block.

It's worth noting that Views does indeed have some overhead, but in my experience, its flexibility and ease-of-use far outweigh the relatively minor performance hit.

If you'd like to avoid using Views, you could write a pretty simple custom module using hook_block() and adapting http://drupal.org/node/247472. If you'd like, I can edit this answer with an example module based on that.

Comment: i'm trying to boost the performance too, so yes please. i'd love to see it as a module. thank you!

Comment: View will display terms as plain list.

Answer (score 1):

(Posting this as another answer, since this is a different approach than my first answer.)

As I mentioned above, here's another approach involving a custom module based on the code at http://drupal.org/node/247472. You could also just drop that code into a custom block with the "PHP" input format selected, but that's generally considered to be bad practice.

Add a new folder in sites/all/modules called **vocabulary_block**. Customize and add the following two files:

**vocabulary_block.module**

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Exposes a block with a simple list of terms from [vocabulary]. 
 * Each term is linked to its respective term page.
 */

/**
* Lists terms for a specific vocabulary without descriptions.
* Each term links to the corresponding /taxonomy/term/tid listing page.
*/
function vocabulary_block_get_terms($vid) {
  $items = array();

  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid,  0, -1, 1);
  foreach($terms as $term) {
    $items[]= l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid");
  }
  if(count($items)) {
    return theme('item_list', $items);
  }
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block().
 */
function vocabulary_block_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
  switch ($op) {

    case 'list':
      $blocks[0]['info'] = t('List of [vocabulary] terms');
      return $blocks;

    case 'view':
      if ($delta == 0) {
        $vid = 43;
        $block['subject'] = t('[Vocabulary]');
        $block['content'] = vocabulary_block_get_terms($vid);
      }

      return $block;
  }    
}
```

**vocabulary_block.info**

```
name = Vocabulary Block
description = Exposes a block with a simple list of terms from [vocabulary]. Each term is linked to its respective term page.

; Core version (required)
core = 6.x

; Package name (see http://drupal.org/node/101009 for a list of names)
package = Taxonomy

; Module dependencies
dependencies[] = taxonomy
```

**Notes**

- Be sure to change `$vid = 43;` to
  reflect the ID of the vocabulary that
  you'd like to load. You can find the
  VID by visiting
  admin/content/taxonomy and looking at
  the destination of the **edit
  vocabulary** link for your
  vocabulary. The VID will be the last
  fragment of that URL:
  admin/content/taxonomy/edit/vocabulary/**[vid]**.

  I wouldn't normally hard-code the
  $vid into the module itself. However,
  setting up the necessary Drupal
  variable and administration form (to
  allow users to select a vocabulary
  from the Drupal interface) would be
  overkill for this answer.
- For your own documentation purposes,
  don't forget to search/replace
  [vocabulary] in those two files and
  use your own vocabulary's name
  instead.
- This method *may not necessarily* be more performant
  than the Views method I described 
  earlier, especially once you start considering caching,
  optimization, etc.
  Since performance is a priority,
  I recommend thoroughly testing a 
  variety of different methods on this page and
  choosing whichever one is fastest for you.